# Facebook oauth2 - secure after-login use

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0

I would like to ask little theoretically.

I have an angular6 + spring app that has its own client, app-specific client data.
These data can be divided into two groups

1. managment-data: Like client roles that allow client to visit different parts of app
2. client-data: personal settings, history of activities etc.

Because I would like to make login as user-friendly as possible, I would like to implement facebook login.

After user click "FB login button", facebook returns me some-user info and mainly a security token. How could I use this to securely communicate with my BE.

When someone sends request to BE, I need to be sure, that its the same person that logged in to facebook.

1. If I send this token as part of request, what stops possible attacker to somehow obtain token and then impersonate original user?
2. In what form I should send data I got from Facebook to my own server?
3. How should I work with token on server?
4. How can I validate its authenticity?

Thank you for answers

Filip Širc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into the usage of [OpenID Connect](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html) along with OAuth protocol. It allows you to authenticate the user to your client application (Angular6 + Spring app) to verify the user details.

When you are sending an `access token` to access a certain resource, you should avoid sending it as a request parameter. Usually it is encouraged to send it under the Authorization header of the request as a `bearer token`. However, if you want it to be extra secure, you could encode the token before sending so that it would be difficult to decode it and steal any valuable information.

Also, when you are sending sensitive information, it ise better to send them in the form of a `JSON Web Token (JWT)`. You can use a third party library to create a jwt to include the information that need to be sent to the server. You can sign the jwt with your own signature which can be validated later. Refer https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519 for detailed information about jwts.

You should use the claims in your `access token` to grant a user access to the resource you are protecting. Since most of the tokens are sent in the form of jwts, you can decode them and get check the necessary claims such as scopes, audience (client app), subject (user), etc.

Most importantly, you should validate the signature of the token sent from Facebook to make sure its an authentic one. For this, you have to get the `public key` details from Facebook's `jwks endpoint` and validate the signature using a third party library (auth0, nimbusds, etc.). Facebook's digital signature will be unique and this verification process is the best way to ensure the security. Also, you can check whether certain claims in the token match your expected values to validate the token. This can also be done through libraries such as ones mentioned above. Here's [auth0 repo](https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt) for you to get a general idea.

Comment: Thank you for help (and also for correcting mistakes in my question :-) )

Comment: No problem. If you think this answer helped you to find a solution, click the tick button to accept the answer. :)